# Udev rules for a device with multiple interfaces

Tags: usb, udev

So, I'm delving into udev and running into an issue.

I think that I understand the basic premise (please correct me if i'm wrong). Device is attached either due to your system booting up or sometime afterwards. Udev goes through all the rules looking for matches. once it finds a match, it executes whatever actions were requested, and continues going down the list of rules until it gets to the last one. Then it starts off on the next device.

Now, I have a usb device that creates 2 interfaces. When I attach it, i get both an can0 and can1 when I look in `/sys/class/net/`. But in `/dev`, there is only one entry for this under `/dev/bus/usb/002/00X`.

Now, here is where my problem comes. I want to name each of these interfaces something specific. I know that one always comes up before the other. If i do nothing, they get named `can0` and `can1`. If I put a udev rule in, the first one that comes up gets renamed properly, but looking at the `dmesg` logs, the second one errs out because the kernel name is also `can0` (since there is no `can1`).

How would one get around this? `udevadm` doesn't help since there is only one device listed in `/dev`, so it seems that I can't differentiate them by attributes.

output of `lsusb -v` below:

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0c72:0011 PEAK System 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0c72 PEAK System
  idProduct          0x0011 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 PEAK-System Technik GmbH
  iProduct                2 PCAN-USB Pro FD
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          111
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 Config00
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              240mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           6
      bInterfaceClass         0 (Defined at Interface level)
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 PCAN-USB Pro FD CAN
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           6
      bInterfaceClass         0 (Defined at Interface level)
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              6 PCAN-USB Pro FD LIN
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x86  EP 6 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: Use `lsusb` to find some property that distinguishes between the two interfaces, then use that property to write two `udev` rules.

Comment: @SatōKatsura The problem I'm having is that since there is only one usb device, and network interfaces aren't stored in /dev. With ethernet, the way someone would have separated them would have been through the mac address, but can doesn't have any similarly identifying features.

This is my understanding based on my research. please correct me if i'm wrong or misunderstanding your comment

Comment: No. Since it's an USB device, dig around with `lsusb` at increasing verbosity levels.  At some point you should be able to detect _some_ difference between _some_ attributes of the two interfaces.  Most of the attributes listed by `lsusb` also map to `udev` attributes (provided you're brave enough to read through the docs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As seen in `lsusb -v`, your interfaces have different names. This can be additionally checked by

```
udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n can0)
udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n can1)
```

Therefore you can use `ATTR{interface}` to distinguish them.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0c72", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0011", ATTR{interface}=="PCAN-USB Pro FD CAN"
```

Note that above we use specific combination of `ATTR` and `ATTRS` keys that matters because we look for values in current or current and parent device, see http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html.

If interfaces names are the same then they can be distinguished by `ATTR{bInterfaceNumber}`.

Comment: Oh wow, I had forgotten this question was still out there. I figured it out a little earlier, and it was the exact same thing only difference was that when using udevadm, i gave it the actual path of the network interface (/sys/class/net...) instead of searching for it. And yes bInterfaceNumber was the only differing attribute.